# Do certain operations for x seconds and then exit

Tags: ruby

Is there some block in Ruby that will allow me to put anything in that code, say 5 methods, which take a variable amount of time to complete. The block should stop executing the code inside it as soon as 5 seconds pass. I know Timeout enables something like this, but would prefer something that doesn't raise an exception in case the timeout passed for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a `Thread` and then `kill`ing it after a specified amount of time:

```
t = Thread.new {
  sleep 1
  puts 'after 1'
  sleep 2
  puts 'after 2'
  sleep 3
  puts 'after 3'
  sleep 4
  puts 'after 4'
}

sleep 5
t.kill
```

Output:

```
after 1
after 2
```